# Nodejs rest service

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, rest

I am trying to create REST service using Nodejs and Mysql.
his is my code:

```
var sqlDb = require("mysql"); 
var settings = require("../settings");
exports.executeSql = function (sql, callback) {
var conn = sqlDb.createConnection(settings.dbConfig);
conn.connect()
.then(function () {
    var req = new sqlDb.Request(conn);
    req.query(sql)
    .then(function (recordset) {
        callback(recordset);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback(null, err); 
    });
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    callback(null, err);
});
```

};

But I have an error

```
.then(function(){
 ^
TypeError: cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The correct function is `createConnection`. Read the docs please:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#introduction

Comment: thanks for your answer. But when I use 'createConnection' I have another error 'Cannot read property then of undefined'.

Comment: Because `then` is a promise approach totally unnecessary. There is a different approach proposed by `mysql` and you can read about it in docs (again, read docs): https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#establishing-connections

Comment: Note that if you absolutely need to use Promises, take a look at Bluebird : https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird or q : https://www.npmjs.com/package/q
which are 2 great libraries to deal with Promises.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, the **`connect`** method is not returning a promise if you look at the [documentation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#establishing-connections) this can work as *callback* method:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'example.org',
  user     : 'bob',
  password : 'secret'
});

//** Look here...
connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }
  console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});
```

As a good alternative, you can use the package **`promise-mysql`** that is using bluebird and you can locate [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql) (which I strongly suggest to use) or you can wrap it up in a promise like using bluebird like:

```
async function connect(connection) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      connection.connect((err) => {
         return err ? reject(err) : resolve(connection);
      })
   });
}
```